# Linux/c++ log rotation scheme

Tags: c++, linux, logging, rotation

I have a logger system which basically is a fancy way of writing my data to std::clog in a thread safe way.

I also, redirect `std::clog` to a file like this:

```
int main() {
    std::ofstream logfile(config::logname, std::ios::app);
    std::streambuf *const old_buffer = std::clog.rdbuf(logfile.rdbuf());

    // .. the guts of the application

    std::clog.rdbuf(old_buffer);
}
```

This works great... however, my application also produces a very large amount of logs. I was wondering what would be a good way to properly rotate my log files. Is there a safe way to switch out the file via a cron task? I would guess no.

The only thing I can think of that would definitely work is if I had the application itself open a new file, and redirect the rdbuf of clog to that while holding the logging mutex. But that feels like a cheap solution, and I would need to check so see if it is time to rotate logs fairly often for it to be effective. There has got to be a better way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the built-in log rotation method configured in /etc/logrotate.conf and/or /etc/logrotate.d/ - it's common to have logrotate send your app a SIGUSR1 as a signal to close and re-open all your log files.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is I add a SIGUSR1 handler which does a close/reopen while holding the logging lock and logrotate will signal my app with that periodically?

Comment: Even, only if you configure logrotate to rotate your logs, and set it to send a SIGUSR1 to your app.  It doesn't happen automatically.

Answer (score 7):

Or just use syslog instead of your custom logging scheme and the logs get rotated by logrotate anyway. -- depending on how it's configured but on most desktop/server systems it's already set to rotate them.

Comment: Good answer, but at this point I'd prefer to stick to my current logging scheme.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to the following, and move the log file away whichever way (logrotate, cron script, etc.) (providing Cish sample, should be easily convertible)

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void logworker()
{
    ino_t inode = 0;
    FILE *logfile;

    logfile = fopen(logfilename, "a+");
    while(running)
    {
        struct stat mystat;

        if (stat(logfilename, &mystat)!=0 || mystat.st_ino != inode)
        {
            logfile = freopen(logfilename, "a+", logfile);
            inode = mystat.st_ino;
        }

        while (stuff_in_buffer)
        {
            fwrite(); /* etc */
        }
        fflush(logfile);

        /* sleep until something interesting happens */
    }
}
```

It is safe to write to a file after it has been moved, so there's no need for extra caution